# Combine lists horizontally in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I combine lists like these:

(list A in the buffer)

```
apple
business
car
```

(list B in the clipboard)

```
sauce
school
driving
```

to get a result like this? :

(if I run some function at the end of the element "boy" in the list A)

```
apple sauce
business school
car driving
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid [Rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) are your best bet.

You can later remove extra space using <kbd>M-Space</kbd>.